# Error al implementar FirebaseAuth AuthStateListener

Tags: android, firebase

Me gustaría conseguir el siguiente flujo en mi App:

1. El usuario se registra, valida email y luego inicia sesión
2. Una vez dentro, si elimino la cuenta desde la consola de Firebase, redirigir al usuario a MainActivity (porque obviamente ya no tiene una cuenta)

Tengo todo, menos lo de verificar si el usuario es `null`. He tratado de hacerlo pero, el App se cierra y recibo el error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener.onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)' on a null object reference

A parte de esto, para que aparezca el `Toast`, debo ir a otro `Activity` y luego volver para que se ejecute el `Listener`. No se supone que funcione dentro del mismo Activity?

La idea es siempre revisar si el usuario que está en el App es válido o no (ejemplo, si ha sido eliminado o si la cuenta ha sido desactivada).

Código:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged (@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth){
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "User is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "User is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

}
```

Estoy usando:

1. Android Studio 3.1.4
2. `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'`

Alguna idea de el por qué no me funciona?

Comment: tu objetivo es chequear si el usuario esta logueado no ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén Si el usuario está logeado y elimino su cuenta desde la consola de Firebase, me gustaría poder enviarlo a MainActivity, es decir, cerrar su sesión (porque obviamente ya no tiene una cuenta). Pensé que con un Listener se mantendría escuchando los cambios pero no, solo se ejecuta el Listener una vez, cuando abres el App.

Comment: lo que pasa es que no cerras la conexion con firebase si lo borras de la base de datos, deberias hacer un FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(); y un listener que escuche al valor de la key guardada en firebase, si no existe mas el UID del usuario que te desconecte de firebase y te mande a otro lado

Comment: @GastónSaillén Exacto. Mi Listener no se mantiene escuchando, solo funciona la primera vez, cuando abres el App. Podrías editar tu respuesta con un ejemplo aplicando lo que dices? Me sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: ahi edite la respuesta

Comment: en el onCreate reemplaza eso que pusiste por lo de abajo mio, si usas mAuth.addAuthStateListener si va a escuchar todo el tiempo en la Activity si esta o no logueado, como lo tenes vos, solamente inicias el listener en el onStart pero nunca tenes algo que escuche todo el tiempo si el usuario esta o no conectado, con el codigo de abajo deberia funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podes hacer para chequear si el usuario en cuestion esta o no logueado al ingresar a `onCreate()` es lo siguiente

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() { 
@Override 
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) { 
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(); 
if (user != null) { 
checkUserExists();
} else { 

      // El usuario es null
      } 
   } 
};
```

Metodo para chequear si el usuario existe o no de la base de datos

```
private void checkUserExists(){

   //y aca vemos si no es null , chequeamos que exista en la base de datos
                mDatabase.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists())

                        //codigo si existe usuario
                          else
                        //Llevar a otra Activity u otra opcion


                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                }
            });


 }
```

Acordate de atachar el listener del auth en el `onStart()`

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart(); 

         mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    }
```